# Is it unPythonic to ask the package's user to extend a class, but the user cannot instantiate it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, plugins

I'm writing the Python bindings of a C library which allows the user to create custom "classes" in C and instantiate them through another object, something like:

```c
my_class = create_class(init_callback, finalize_callback, ...);
instance1 = manager_create_object(some_manager, my_class, ...);
instance2 = manager_create_object(some_manager, my_class, ...);
```

Unfortunately, the C language is not object-oriented, so this library uses the concept within the limits of what the language offers.

In Python, for a user to define its own class, I'd like to use the concept of a Python class:

```py
class MyClass(package.BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...

    def _finalize(self, ...):
        ...


instance1 = some_manager.create_object(MyClass, ...)
instance2 = some_manager.create_object(MyClass, ...)
```

I cannot instantiate the object directly with `MyClass()` because it needs said manager (see `manager_create_object()` above).

Is it weird/unPythonic to ask the user to extend the package's class (`package.BaseClass` in this example) without being able to instantiate the derived class (`MyClass`) directly with `MyClass()`? This is mostly for a plugin interface, where we would need the user to define one or more classes in a Python module file.

Answer (score 0):

It's not unusual to insist that the user (client side) supply a local implementation of certain capabilities, especially if you can supply examples and/or templates for the needed support.  Many suppliers do this, as they cannot cover all of the implementations.

However, make *sure* that you give a wide variety of examples.  You want to make it easy for your users.  Better yet, deliver files that constitute working implementations for several popular environments.